# Preferred Domain (in Webmaster Tools) and IIS7 Configuration

Tags: iis-7, dns, google-search-console

I am setting up a new website and want to set the non-www version as the preferred domain in Google Webmaster tools.

In IIS7 I was going to configure the non-www domain as the main site, then configure a redirect for the www domain to perform a 301 redirect to the non-www domain (as I want *all* traffic that requests www. regardless of whether it's the homepage or any page within the site) to redirect to the equivalent page on the non-www version.

I have set the above up and all works fine, however, in order to set the preferred domain in Google Webmaster tools, I need to verify both the www and non-www domains. My question is, if I have set up a 301 redirect for all www requests to go to non-www, how can I verify the www domain (as google won't be able to reach a verification file on the www domain)?

Comment: This isn't really a SO question. It would be more suitable for [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that you can add a TXT entry to your DNS record and verify the domain in webmaster tools this way, which solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's why first you have to verify your www domain in webmaster tools, after that set up your preferred domain and than you can remove www domain from your webmaster tools admin section. Now you can set your 301 redirect. Your preferred domain is already choosen and you don't need verification any more.